# How can I query the domain name with subdomains levels?

Tags: mysql

I have a field contains domain names. The domain names vary in their levels. for example, I have some like: `shopping.yahoo.com` and some as `www.mail.yahoo.com` and some as `yahoo.com` while others as: `www.yahoo.com`.

I need to query all the domain names that have more than the second level domain name. i.e, more than the format: `domain.ext` (ex: `shopping.yahoo.com` or `www.shopping.yahoo.com` or `men.shopping.yahoo.com`).

I'm not expert in Mysql but I need to do this query. Sorry for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could base your query on number of periods like this

```
SELECT * from table where domain_field LIKE('%.%.%')
```